# Can not install wine32 on ubuntu22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, wine

I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 22.04 with

> sudo apt-get install wine

I also add i386 architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

It installs wine and wine64. That's  OK but, when i tried to install `wine32` it gives me following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grep : PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
 libglib2.0-0 : Depends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
                Recommends: shared-mime-info
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not going to be installed
 librdf0 : Depends: librasqal3 (>= 0.9.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: `wine64` will be just fine in running 64-bit or 32-bit (or even 16-bit) Windows programs.

Comment: But when i check the version of wine it says `it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"`

Comment: please add `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` Maybe jammy-updates or jammy-security is not enabled.